# Ribbon application menu (dropdown) is not minimizing (closing or losing focus) in WPF application while loading after a click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu, ribbon

I have a wpf application with ribbon included. The ribbon has application menu which is a dropdown like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3m6.png). This application menu has list of recent file for opening a file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hfzH.png). Now when a user select one recent file from the list, this dropdown get stuck until the file is loaded. The dropdown comes on top of any other application like powerpoint if I open it parallelly while the file is being loaded like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/266Ca.png) . I want the dropdown to close while the file is being loaded so that I can show some progress bar or loading icon.

The xaml code is given below.

```
<Ribbon>
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu >
                <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Recent}" />
                        <Separator />
                        <RibbonGallery
                            CanUserFilter="False"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <RibbonGalleryCategory Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}">
                                <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
                                <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.InputBindings>
                                                <MouseBinding
                                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.opencommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}"
                                                    MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                                            </Grid.InputBindings>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Numero}" TextDecorations="Underline" />
                                            <TextBlock
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                                Text="{Binding FileName}"
                                                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                ToolTip="{Binding FilePath}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
                            </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                        </RibbonGallery>
                    </StackPanel>
                </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu> >
    </Ribbon>
```

Please help me with any idea. I tried replacing textblock with ribbonbutton but the click event was not working. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bind a boolean to Ribbon.IsDropDownOpen and set it false before loading the file. Maybe you'll have to use the Dispatcher to make it work.

Comment: Hi David, I tried
 Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => RibbonAppMenu.IsDropDownOpen = false); 
but it does not seem to work. Do I need to make any changes in XAML?

Comment: Try with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(().... other than I'm out of ideas